# What in place sort when two arrays are in order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, in-place

[I am working on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673854/sort-with-threads/4674052). My function prototype is

```
static void Sort(byte[] arr, int leftPos, int rightPos)
```

In the 2nd part of the function i know leftPos to leftPos + (rightPos-leftPos)/2 and (rightPos-leftPos)/2 to rightPos are sorted in order.

I tried thinking of how i could do an in place sort knowing the two parts are in order. I couldnt think of any. I looked at the merge function on [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) but it uses an output array rather than in place.

How do i sort it in place knowing both slices are in order?

Note: I was thinking i could pass in a extra array that is the same length as the main array to use as temp memory but the way i thought of would require me to do Array.Copy after each merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-place merge is possible, but it's complicated and doesn't give much performance gain. Below is some sample code from [here](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/inplacestablesort.html). `from` is your `leftPos`, `to` is your `rightPos`, `pivot` is your `(rightPos-leftPos)/2` and the lengths are the lengths of each half.

```
void merge(int from, int pivot, int to, int len1, int len2) {
  if (len1 == 0 || len2==0) return;
  if (len1+len2 == 2) {
   if (compare(pivot, from) < 0)
    exchange(pivot, from);
   return;
  }
  int first_cut, second_cut;
  int len11, len22;
  if (len1 > len2) {
   len11=len1/2;
   first_cut = from + len11;
   second_cut = lower(pivot, to, first_cut);
   len22 = second_cut - pivot;
  } else {
   len22 = len2/2;
   second_cut = pivot + len22;
   first_cut = upper(from, pivot, second_cut);
   len11=first_cut - from;
  }
  rotate(first_cut, pivot, second_cut);
  int new_mid=first_cut+len22;
  merge(from, first_cut, new_mid, len11, len22);
  merge(new_mid, second_cut, to, len1 - len11, len2 - len22);
}
```

Comment: What is lower and upper btw? rotate.... while looking at this, it appears it is better if i just used a 2nd array and use array.copy. It be much less lines then this + functions missing (all i notice are lower, upper and rotate)

Comment: @acid I quoted the [source](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/inplacestablesort.html) which defines those functions. I agree though - it's unlikely to be worth the effort as you're adding overhead to keep things in-place. I was just showing you it can be done if necessary.