# Is Array.Sort() Multithreaded in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I know that `Array.Sort()` in VB.NET uses the quicksort algorithm.  But my question is, does it take advantage of multithreading?

I'm sorting a list of hundreds of thousands of records, and need to ensure the fastest sort times.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the code in mscorlib, is doesn't appear to. Have you tried just running it? Does it meet your current performance goals?

Comment: This is in production code, and it takes about 4-5 seconds to sort a list of 100k rows.  It's ultimately faster for me to do a requery to the database and apply the sorting in the SQL query.  I don't want to do this do, so I'm not putting an extra load on our database server just to sort the results.

Comment: What type of data are you sorting? If it's based on integer keys, then you might have some success with using a radix sort. You also might give the *appearance* of improved performance with an intelligent caching layer. Without knowing more specifics, it's hard to give much more advice.

Comment: I'm sorting my own object, which I call "Document".  I contains around 20 or so properties, and is displayed in a grid.  When a user clicks on a column, it basically calls the .Sort() method of a collection.  I do have a class that implements IComparer to do the comparison, and there's nothing that can be done to improve its performance.

Comment: In that case, I can't think of a lot that can be done. Sorting 100K+ records is going to be a time-consuming operation, especially with non-trivial comparands.

Comment: I would question the wisdom of putting 100K rows in a grid on the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how multi-threading would make your sorting faster.
`Array.Sort` does sorting in a single thread.

If by multi-threading you actually mean **taking advantage of several processors when they are available**, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897458/parallel-sort-algorithm) that uses [Parallel Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx) (available in .NET 4.0 and [partly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project) available for .NET 3.5).

Comment: Thanks, this may be what I need.  I'm surprised that Microsoft that does not have an impementation of this?  I've been adjusting to using Parallel.ForEach() in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's going to give you a real performance boost though. I would rather try to optimize the `IComparer` using a profiler.

Comment: Also, don't hesitate posting comparer code in another question—people might notice something you might've missed, e.g. expensive boxing operations.

Comment: I guess my thought was if we have 4 processors, divide up the list into four parts, and have the 4 processors each work on sorting those 4 parts.  It may be just as expensive to combine these back together.  Does anyone have any hard numbers on a proven sorting algorithm that takes advantage of multiple cores, or is there not a solution?

Comment: @user842818, check out Divide & Conquer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm